# What is the host key of Windows 7 Virtual PC and where can you change it?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

Does anyone know which key is the host key of Windows 7 Virtual PC and where I could change it to a different one? Before Windows 7 the host key was changed in the option menu of Virtual PC but the new version is integrated into the explorer so there is no option menu for Virtual PC.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/57043/what-is-the-host-key-of-windows-7-virtual-pc-and-where-can-you-change-it :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot change it. It is fixed to Ctrl+Alt+Left.

Comment: ... which works pretty poorly on computers where you change the (host) screen orientation with Ctrl+Alt+Left, Right, Up and Down.

Answer (score 2):

Right here, Virtual PC -> File -> Options.
I use Scroll lock because i never ever used that key for something and i need right alt.

[image: File -> options]

I know it's been 2 years :)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7, Default Virtual PC 2007 install. Pound on the Right Alt key all day for great fun, or press CTL-ALT-Left or Right Arrow and escape the window to return to the Host...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 7 and Virtual PC 2007, the host key for me is the right ALT key. Unfortunatley I don't know were or if its possible to change it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the Virtual PC within Windows Explorer and select Settings.
2. Under Settings, select Keyboard.
3. Under "Send Windows key combinations such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>", select "To the virtual machine".

This will send your keyboard commands to the Virtual PC and you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> to release the mouse cursor from the Virtual PC.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but to see this in current versions (Oracle VirtualBox Manager 5.2.22), go to <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd>  > <kbd>Input (from left column)</kbd> > <kbd>Virtual Machine tab.</kbd>

[image]

Click on it to change. An errase icon also appears the the right in the box. Press that to delete it. Now select a new key while focus is in this control.

Note, it doesn't select every key for example a normal alphanumric numeric key is not a valid entry. But you can select the special keys.

Answer (score -1):

Its depends which tool you are using for Virtual Machine. In Oracle VM VirtualBox the Host Key is **Right Ctrl** Key.

Comment: The user explicity said Windows 7 Virtual PC.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using a Virtual Machine (Oracle VM VirtualBox) on Windows 10 and I found the Host Key by pressing the **Right Ctrl key**.

Comment: The question was about Virtual PC not VirtualBox.